# IntelliJ linking to the wrong source code, maven project

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea, playframework, intellij-13

I have a play framework project built by maven and imported to IntelliJ.

The project runs fine and compile with no problem.

However, when I want to see some source code of the Play Framework. For example

```
public FakeRequest(String method, String path) {
    this.fake = play.api.test.FakeRequest.apply(method, path); 
}
```

When I click to the "play.api.test.FakeRequest.apply" , (It said "sources not found"), and displayed me the following file
class file under

```
..../repository/com/typesafe/play/play-test_2.10/2.2.2/play-test_2.10-2.2.2.jar!/play/api/test/FakeRequest.class
```

however, the actual java file is located at

```
...../repository/com/typesafe/play/play-test_2.10/2.2.2/play-test_2.10-2.2.2-sources.jar!/play/test/FakeRequest.java
```

I have tried

1. Re-import the project , does not help
2. File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart
3. cloned a project again from git

But all these approaches didn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven toolwindow click on "Download sources and documentation", see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-projects-tool-window.html. You change also change the default in Maven project settings.